# Iphone - animations and accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

There is an accelerometer and animation. When the device is shaken animation begins to play, when, during the animation device is shaken again, the animation runs again (this is logical). The question of how to do so would while playing the animation even if the device is shaken the animation does not start anew? Methods & motionEnded motionBegan I do not use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of animation you use in your code. If it's a simple UIImageView animation then you can use (BOOL)isAnimating function of the UIImageView class to prevent the animation sequence to start again if it's running. Hope this helps.

Comment: a simple animation uiimageviev but still it works crookedly :(